# sorting pandas dataframe by column alphabetically after first 4 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

I have a dataframe like this

```
    new_col    new_elements       new_val     old_col   old_elements   old_val
 0  0          384444683          593         2         423483819      480
 1  1          384444684          594         32        248239340      341
 2  2          384444686          596         0         249289049      342
```

and I want this:

```
    new_col    old_col   new_elements      old_elements     new_val     old_val   
 0  0          2         384444683         423483819        593         480     
 1  1          32        384444684         248239340        594         341
 2  2          0         384444686         249289049        596         342
```

I know that `df.sort_index(axis=1)` will alphabetically sort my columns, but they already are sorted that way now. What I want is for them to be sorted alphabetically after the prefix (first 4 characters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also `sort_index` providing a key:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda s: s.str[4:])

    new_col     old_col     new_elements    old_elements    new_val     old_val
0   0   2   384444683   423483819   593     480
1   1   32  384444684   248239340   594     341
2   2   0   384444686   249289049   596     342
```

Answer (score 2):

```
col = df.columns
col = sorted(col,key=lambda x: x[4:])
col
df = df[col]
df
```

[image]

Putting altogether `df = df[sorted(df.columns,key=lambda x: x[4:])]`

Comment: @tkxgoogle If this answers your question, please kindly check the tick to accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but this is how I'd go about it:

```
fields = ['new_col', 'old_col', 'new_elements', 'old_elements', 'new_val', 'old_val']

df = df[fields]
```